# ECM Acadia SLT with Enclave engine

Tags: electronic-control-module, gmc, acadia

I have a 2007 Acadia SLT with a 2008 Enclave engine . I have a couple of codes that keep coming back . P0036 P0024 they will not clear . Can I reprogram the ECM or do I have to get an ECM for that Enclave engine .

Comment: Did you address and troubleshoot the downstream O2 sensor heater and/or circuitry related to P0036? Did you address and troubleshoot cam timing related to P0024?

Comment: All new sensors

Comment: O2 sensor heaters requires 12v power on cold engine startup, then goes away. Measured for 12v? I don't know what voltage goes to the cam sensor or output signal.